# Are the stiefel-Whitney classes of the tangent bundle determined by the mod 2 cohomology?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, symplectic-topology, dg.differential-geometry

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Let $f\colon L \to N$ be a smooth map of connected smooth **closed** $n$-dimensional manifolds such that the induced map

$$f^* \colon H^*(N,G) \to H^*(L,G)$$

is an isomorphism.

**Question**: Are the pull back of the Stiefel-Whitney classes of the tangent bundle of $N$ the Stiefel-Whitney classes of the tangent bundle of $L$?.

This is in fact true for the first Stiefel-Whitney class by considering coverings and degrees, but what about the higher degree classes?

**Motivation**: This came up because (relative) spin is important in defining Floer homology with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients. So I am in fact mostly interested in the following sub-question.

**Question**: In particular what about the second Stiefel-Whitney class in the case where both $N$ and $L$ are also assumed to be oriented? and if the answer is negative: what extra conditions do I need to make it positive?

The idea is that I apriori have to use $G$ coefficients, but can prove that it is a $G$-cohomology equivalence, and want to use that to start the argument over again with other coefficients, but for that I need this property of the second Stiefel-Whitney class.

This sub-question and the relation to Floer homology is related to orientations in real $K$-theory and delooping in the following sense: take a map $h\colon X \to U/O$ by delooping we get a map $\Omega h \colon \Omega X \to \Omega U/O \simeq \mathbb{Z}\times BO$ which classifies a virtual bundle over the loop space of $X$. This bundle is oriented iff the original map composed with the canonical map $U/O \to BO$ classified a virtual $0$-dimensional bundle with vanishing second Stiefel-Whitney class. This is the main point of why orientations in Floer homology is initimitely linked with spin! In the case of a Lagrangian sub-manifold $L\subset T^*N$ the difference of the tangent bundles precisely defines such a map $L \to U/O$ ($U(n)/O(n)$ classifies Lagrangians in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$) such that the composition to $BO$ classifies the virtual bundle $TN-TL$. So in fact you may add this lifting property as an extra condition to the sub-question if you like, and then I would lose no generality. I believe that this condition implies that all the relative Prontryagin classes vanishes, which may be helpfull.

ADDED: in light of the answer, all this motivation and these extra possible assumptions are not important nor relevant for the actual question.

Comment: "Floer homology is oriented iff you have spin!" Um... Relative pin structures are sufficient to determine coherent orientations, but I'm not sure I'd care to formulate a converse. Two disjoint Lagrangians have a natural (but trivial!) Floer complex over the integers.

Comment: By the way, the (excellent!) idea that one should prove that nearby Lagrangians are mod 2 cohomology equivalent and hence relatively spin is I believe one that Fukaya-Seidel-Smith were aware of when they wrote their papers on nearby Lagrangians. They couldn't use it because they invoke a theorem that requires char $\neq 2$. But it comes up at the very end of Abouzaid's preprint http://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.0358.

Comment: @Tim: The Floer homology I am refering to is the one for the action of a given Hamiltonian on a symplectic manifold $M$, not the intersection Floer homology for two Lagrangians, which I admit is a not obvious from the above since I am explicitly considering a Lagrangian in $T^*N$ (this is also what Viterbo did in "Exact Lagrange submanifolds, periodic orbits and the cohomology of the free loop space", and I am working in the same spirit), in this case the Floer homology can be given coherent orientations without employing any tricks iff $M$ is spin,

Comment: and in the case Viterbo considers the generating functions are related by an **oriented** bundle iff $L\to N$ is relative spin. Thanks for the reference I had not seen that one, I am looking forward to seing if the passage from homology equivalence to homotopy equivalence can work in my frame work as well.

Comment: I realize now that something is not quite right about this statement because Floer homology can be oriented in the case of $T^*N$ even if $N$ is not spin. I am not sure anymore what precisely the general statement is, but at least the orientation is intimitely linked to spin, because of what I write, and the relative spin statement about generating functions is valid in the Viterbo case. (I have changed the statement)

Comment: Ups nothing was wrong i think! $T^*N$ is spin even if $N$ is not. This is because that the tangent space $T_{(q,p)}(T^*N)$ is two times $T_qN$ at each point $(q,p)\in T^*N$ so we have the formula for the total class that $\omega(T(T^*N)\to TN)=\omega(TN\to N)^2$, and if $N$ is oriented then that implies that the square has vanishing second class.

Comment: Hamiltonian Floer homology is always defined integrally. This is reasonable: the determinant index bundle over the space of complex-linear Cauchy-Riemann operators is oriented. One way to get coherent orientations is to view it as Lagrangian Floer homology $HF(\Delta,\Delta)$ where $\Delta\subset N\times N$ is the diagonal. These two Lagrangians are canonically spin relative to the vector bundle $p_1^*TN$. (Also relative to $p_2^*TN$, though I haven't compared the resulting coherent orientations). 

Comment: hmm Ok... I must have missed something somewhere. At least the case I am interested in where I look at generating functions a la Viterbo it is spin that makes the bundles oriented, and I can prove that these bundles are not oriented if $L\to N$ is not relative spin. Thanks for clearing up the general picture for me.

Comment: (When I said that Ham HF is always defined integrally, I should have said rationally, because of bubbling. Excuse me.) I don't know the generating function story. It may be that there are subtleties there, or it may be (as in the case of Floer-Hofer's paper on coherent orientations in Hamiltonian HF) that the topology can be simplified. I believe that orientations for Lagrangian HF were only understood later than Viterbo's paper, around 2000, in Vin de Silva's thesis and in Fukaya-Oh-Ohta-Ono's book.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer to the question is positive, due to Wu's formula. See e.g. Milnor-Stasheff, Characteristic classes, lemma 11.13 and theorem 11.14. In fact, all one needs to compute the Stiefel-Whitney classes of a smooth compact manifold (orientable or not) is the cohomology mod 2 (as an algebra) and the action of the Steenrod algebra on it. Both structures are preserved under cohomology isomorphisms induced by continuous maps.

Comment: How does this relate to exotic differentiable structures on the sphere? It seems that none of the things you mention as sufficient to calculate S.-W. classes depend on the differentiable structure at all. Are S.-W. classes of the tangent bundle not enough to detect weird smoothness structures? How is the situation different for Pontryagin classes (which is I think what Milnor used to distinguish them)?

Comment: Ilya, homotopy spheres are stably parallelizable. Milnor distinguished exotic 7-spheres via Pontryagin numbers of bounding 8-manifolds.

Comment: Ilya -- yes, the (integral) Pontrjagin classes depend on the smooth structure, but the Stiefel-Whitney classes don't and neither do the rational Pontrjagin classes.

Comment: The Stiefel-Whitney classes don't even depend on the topological structure: They are preserved by homotopy equivalences between closed manifolds. This follows from the positive answer to the question asked. Another perspective on this is that these characteristic classes can be defined for spherical fibrations; you don't need a vector bundle (or even a topological disk bundle or microbundle). They can be defined as the classes that correspond by the Thom isomorphism to the Steenrod squares of the Thom class (and you need only a spherical fibration to get a Thom class and Thom isomorphism).

Comment: But my last comment does not apply at all to the rational Pontrjagin classes. You can give examples of homotopy-equivalent smooth closed manifolds where one is stably parallelizable and the other has nontrivial Pontrjagin classes: the total spaces of the sphere bundles over two vector bundles over a sphere -- one bundle trivial, the other corresponding to a nontrivial element of the kernel of $\pi_{4k}(BO_j)\to pi_{4k}(BG_j)$.

Comment: Tom -- re: the Stiefel-Whitney classes don't even depend on the topological structure. To define the SW classes of a manifold one needs some kind of a bundle (or else what are these classes the classes of?), but once they have been defined, they are preserved by homotopy equivalences (in fact, one only needs a cohomology isomorphism). Re spherical bundle and Thom isomorphism: for a rank $r$ disk bundle over B  it is $H^{\ast}(B)=H^{\ast+r}(E,E_0)$  where $E$ and $E_0$ are the total spaces of the disk bundle, resp. the sphere bundle. But how does one define it if one has a sphere bundle alone?

Comment: algori -- If $E_0\to B$ is a sphere bundle, let $E$ be the mapping cylinder $E=E_0\times[0,1]\cup_{E_0\times0} B$.  That's your disk bundle.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks, Charles; good to know that.

Answer (score 6):

The most conceptual way of understanding the relation between the mod 2 Wu and Stiefel-Whitney classes of a manifold and the action of the Steenrod algebra on the mod 2 cohomology is to use the homotopy theory of Poincare duality spaces and the Spivak normal fibration, and also the chain homotopy theory of chain complexes with symmetric Poincare complexes and the normal chain bundle expounded in my 1980 paper *The algebraic theory of surgery* ([Part I](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/ats1.pdf), [Part II](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/ats2.pdf)). A map $f:L\to N$ of $n$-dimensional manifolds which induces isomorphisms in $Z_2$-coefficient cohomology also induces a chain equivalence of $n$-dimensional symmetric Poincare complexes over $Z_2$. Such a chain equivalence automatically preserves the Spivak normal chain bundles. The mod 2 Wu and Stiefel-Whitney classes of the manifolds are preserved by $f$ because they only depend only on the underlying chain homotopy structure. It is also worth reminding ourselves that Atiyah's 1960 paper *[Thom complexes](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/atiyahthom.pdf)* established the $S$-duality between the Thom space of the normal bundle of a manifold $X$ and $X_+=X \cup \{*\}$, and so proved a conjecture of Milnor and Spanier: *the stable fibre homotopy type of the tangent sphere bundle of a differentiable manifold $X$ depends only on the homotopy type of $X$*.

Answer (score 0):

There was a fundamental error in my answer.

The error was in misunderstanding the naturality of the $w_i$. $f: L \to N$ inducing an isomorphism in cohomology does not imply anything about the induced map of the tangent bundles. This is where i made my fundamental error. Please see the comments for details or look at earlier versions of this answer.

I had hoped that there would be a more "axiomatic" proof in the sense of Milnor and Stasheff. If anyone comes up with one please feel free to put one here.

Thanks to Tom and Dan for the comments!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, because a smooth map $f:N\to L$ need not give a bundle isomorphism, even if it induces isomorphisms on cohomology. 

Comment: Are you saying that f being an isomorphism in mod 2 cohomology implies that `$f^*(\tau_N) = \tau_L$`?

Comment: (My comment is the same as Tom's)

Comment: I did not mean to imply that an isomorphism in cohomology implied that the bundles were isomorphic. My mistake. Do the equations i have above actually require that the map of bundles be an isomorphism of bundles? I believe i only need the bundle map.

If this is wrong, is there a way it can be fixed?

Comment: Any map $X\to Y$ of spaces is covered by a bundle map, for any vector bundles on $X$ and $Y$. (Zero map.) Maybe some books say bundle map when they mean fiberwise isomorphism?

Comment: Ah, yes, i must have been. Thank you for pointing out my mistake. Is there some way this could follow from "the axioms"? Does this really require the wu formula?

Comment: Here is a different argument, but again involving Steenrod squares: Although two homotopy-equivalent manifolds can have different stable normal bundles, the associated sphere bundles are always stably fiber homotopy equivalent. (And, as I mentioned before, that's enough to pin down the $w_i$.) To see this, embed the first manifold in $N$-space for $N>>0$. Embed the second in a tubular neighborhood of the first, by a homotopy equivalence, and make a tubular neighborhood of it. The boundary of the small tube is homotopy equivalent to that of the big tube by a Poincare duality argument.